# Postgresql 12 Replication

Tags: postgresql

для запуска репликации на слейве использовалась pg_basebackup.
Имеем:

1. PostgreSQL 12.18 (Ubuntu 12.18-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit
2. Размер бд = 2Т
3. время выкачки с мастера на слейв более 10 часов;
   pg_basebackup -h 1.2.3.4 -p 5432 -D /database/postgresql12 -U sys_replication -v -P -R -X stream
4. падение реплики после 14 часов работы;
   на мастере видим:

```
    "2024-03-19 01:57:53 MSK [4704]: user=sys_replication,db=[unknown],app=axirate- 
    postgres,client=172.31.1.37(58688)"ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010001CCB30000003A has 
    already been removed
```

на реплике в принципе тоже самое:

```
    "2024-03-19 01:57:53 MSK [3341706]: user=,db=,app=,client="FATAL:  could not receive data 
from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010001CCB30000003A has already been removed
    "2024-03-19 01:57:53 MSK [3256191]: user=,db=,app=,client="LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in 
log segment 000000010001CCB30000003A, offset 4325376
    "2024-03-19 01:57:53 MSK [3520895]: user=,db=,app=,client="LOG:  started streaming WAL from 
primary at 1CCB3/3A000000 on timeline 1
    "2024-03-19 01:57:53 MSK [3520895]: user=,db=,app=,client="FATAL:  could not receive data 
from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010001CCB30000003A has already been removed
```

Утилита pg_basebackup требует наличие пустой datadir (иначе она не запуститься).
Поэтому каждый раз использовать ее для закачки данных на слейв и ждать 10 - 12 часов как то не хочеться.

Архивация WAL файлов на отд. сервере не используется.

На маленьких базах протестировал метод:

```
    1)    pg_start_backup() on the master;
    2)    Stop the replica if running;
    3)    rsync the master to the replica (master ---> replica)
    4)    pg_stop_backup() on the master
    5)    rsync the master to the replica (master ---> replica) only pg_wal directory;
    6)    !!! Check standby.signal and check postgresql.auto.conf
    7)    Start the replica
```

На небольшой базе данный способ работает и реплика запустилаcь.

У меня 2 вопроса:

1. применим ли данный способ на больших базах (2Т) ? Какие могут быть минусы?
2. как использовать вывод команд pg_start_backup и pg_stop_backup ?

pg_stop_backup отдает:

```
    pg_stop_backup
    19/C8000138
```

который может использоваться для выкачки WAL файлов начиная с 19/C8000138. Но как сопоставить это с именем WAL-файла, например 0000000300000019000000C8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ещё это потом работало стабильно, а не отваливалась репликация сразу как чуть отстанет реплика, нужно любым удобным способом обеспечить сохранение для репликации тех WAL, которые больше не нужны самому мастеру. Способы такие (несортированный список):

### Архив WAL

конфигурируете на мастере `archive_mode=on` (требует рестарт базы для включения) и какую-то `archive_command`. Мастер будет вызывает эту `archive_command` для каждого WAL файла и вы куда-то это добро сохраняете. Потом реплика может подтягивать что ей нужно через `restore_command`

Обращаю внимание, это конструктор. Если нет желания разбираться что база ожидает от вас - используйте какой-то готовый механизм. `pgbackrest`, `wal-g` например.

В целом архив WAL - это про бекапы и point-in-time recovery, чем про репликацию. Но если для бекапов этой базы будет нужен архив, то почему бы его и не использовать.

### Слоты репликации

Делаете слот физической репликации (можно попросить pg_basebackup его создать для вас, опция `--create-slot`). Снимаете pg_basebackup с указанием этого слота `--slot=slotname`, потом запускаете реплику. Слот репликации не даст мастеру удалять те WAL, о получении которых ещё не отчиталась реплика.

Но предостерегу: неактивный слот репликации, который допустим забыли и его никто больше не читает, *действительно* не даст удалять старые WAL. Даже когда переполнится диск и база сложится с PANIC.

В pg13 есть настройка `max_slot_wal_keep_size`, какой объём WAL может держать слоты репликации, после чего слот инвалидируется и база удалит эти WAL. Реплика соответственно не сможет продолжить репликацию (если нет архива WAL), но мастер не сложится.

### Хранить фиксированный объём избыточных WAL

настройкой `wal_keep_segments` указываете, сколько WAL файлов базе нужно хранить, даже если они не нужны самой базе для crash recovery. Настройка измеряется числом сегментов WAL, обычно по 16мб каждый (справочная величина  `show wal_segment_size;`). Соответственно, `wal_keep_segments = 100` - 1600мб лага репликации, который реплика сможет догнать самостоятельно без приключений.

начиная с pg13 это настройка `wal_keep_size` и считается уже в мегабайтах, а не сегментах.

Одновременно недостаток и преимущество - это место будет занято постоянно, в отличии от слотов репликации. Отстаёт ли реплика или лага репликации нет, весь заявленный wal_keep_segments (или wal_keep_size) будет на диске занят. Преимущество в том, что если реплика начинает отставать, то у вас стабильный график места на диске, а не начинает внезапно убывать место на мастере.

---

> применим ли данный способ на больших базах (2Т) ? Какие могут быть минусы?

это ровно то же самое, что сделает `pg_basebackup -X fetch`. Не взлетит без архива WAL, без него вы не обеспечите непрерывную историю WAL от `pg_start_backup` до момента запуска `walreceiver`.

> как использовать вывод команд pg_start_backup и pg_stop_backup ?

прочитать в документации. Это низкоуровневый API, не предполагающий использование без понимания как база этим будет пользоваться. Чтобы им воспользоваться и получить внятный результат - прочесть и осмыслить [документацию](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP) необходимо.